# VBA - CopyPaste values with Transpose from multiple workbooks to 1

Tags: excel, vba

Hi VBA experts out there, I am just getting started with VBA and been searching a solution to my issue without any success.

Problem statement:
I have 130 different workbooks that contain data in the same format from which I want to extract and copy certain data (multiple cells arranged in a column, eg A2:A9)
I have 1 consolidating workbook to which I want to transpose the data from each of those 130 workbooks, each in their own single row (A:I).

What I have tried so far and unsuccessfully is:

```
    Sub OpenWorkbook()

  Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\username\Documents\Workbook_xxx.xlsx"
  
  Workbooks("Workbook_001.xlsx").Worksheets("Data").Range("A2:A10").Copy
  
  
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Set wsDest = Workbooks("Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("All Data")
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  Workbooks("Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("All Data").Range("A:I").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
  

Sub CloseWorkbook()

  Workbooks("Workbook_xxx.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True
   
End Sub
```

Please help, I am desperate.

Comment: Oh, and yes, I have searched already the entire stack overflow for something similar and tried to adjust and apply to my situation without any result for 2 days now...

Comment: You just need to loop between the Workbooks.Open and Workbooks.Close section. Does your code work successfully for one workbook?

Comment: @VBAPete I've managed to copy/Paste and transpose one part of the data however I do not know how to do this in bulk with multiple workbooks and copy also different ranges at the same time and paste them in the next available row.